# Weird Rails 4 RESTful URL after form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I have a RESTful controller inside of a namespace called dashboard, so my URL looks like this:

- /dashboard/member
- /dashboard/member/edit

Something weird is happening when I submit the member form with a validation error... it shows the error like it's suppose to, but when it goes to the PATCH url "/dashboard/member" it comes with an ".2" in the end:

- /dashboard/member.2

the "2" is the ID of the record.

The funny thing is that I did everything correctly and it works great, this ".2" is the only thing that is bothering my head.

**My Controller**

```
class Dashboard::MembersController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :class => Member
  before_filter :authenticate_member!

  def show
  end

  def edit
    @member ||= current_member
  end

  def update
    @member ||= current_member
    if @member.update_attributes(member_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to dashboard_member_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private 

  def member_params
    params.require(:member).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :country, :zipcode, :home_phone, :cell_phone)
  end

end
```

**My Route**

```
namespace :dashboard do 
  resource :member, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should paste your `routes.rb` and your view files that access this route.

Comment: Better show your controller, the redirect is probably wrong.

Comment: please so us some code..like routes and links you are using..

Comment: I still believe the error is on the link that redirects to the edit view. Proably some typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to use `resource :member` (instead of `resources :member`) then you should know that it always looks up without referencing an `ID`.

Here is how the routes would be created without id's:

```
 edit_dashboard_member        GET    /dashboard/member/edit(.:format)                              dashboard/members#edit
             dashboard_member GET    /dashboard/member(.:format)                                   dashboard/members#show
                              PATCH  /dashboard/member(.:format)                                   dashboard/members#update
                              PUT    /dashboard/member(.:format)                                   dashboard/members#update
```

When you are sending a PATCH request make sure that you don't pass an `argument` with it. If you pass an argument then it would be interpreted as `format(like .html, .js etc)`. In your case you passed an argument as `2` or a `member with an id 2`

For eg:

PATCH request to dashboard_member_path(2)

The route was matched against `PATCH  /dashboard/member(.:format)                                   dashboard/members#update`

2 is interpreted as `(.:format)` because there is no `:id` part.

Comment: How can I remove the ID from this? can you fix my code?

Comment: Where are you calling the Patch request from? Share that code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the @member from my form, so... I had this:

```
<%= form_for(@member, url: dashboard_member_path(@member), html: {method: "patch", class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

And it became this:

```
<%= form_for(@member, url: dashboard_member_path, html: {method: "patch", class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Now, there's IDs being passed to the URL.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Thats exactly what I told you in my answer, to remove the argument from the call to your PATCH request. As you didn't share the view specific code, I couldn't pinpoint the location. Also, your Original question was about `".2" in the end of PATCH url`and my answer resolves that query. Your answer resolves the question in the comment. Un-accepting the correct answer for the given question is wrong and posting the answer base on the question in comment is again wrong. Answering you wasted my efforts and time.